# CSS change to a squarespace site

Tags: html, css, squarespace

Hi I'm using SquareSpace V6, with the [Momentum template](https://nicholassimmons.squarespace.com/).

in this template there's an option to have the style of your gallery "full-bleed" or simply centered, but this setting is global and it applies to all the galleries on the website.

I'm trying to create some CSS code that will override the default and allow me to have a "full-bleed" gallery in the home page and the home page only, all the other ones will be left centered.

I've been inspecting the code with Chrome and I thought I had it, but nothing changes once I add my code to that specific page:

```
#collection-type-gallery { gallery-style:Full Bleed; }
```

Does anyone has experience with SquareSpace?

Answer (score 0):

not exactly the answer I'm looking for.. but I found a workaround.
I created an empty page and added a background (with a snippet of code) to only that page.
(it only works if you want 1 single fullscreen image)

```
#collection-51b4ef7de4b0_use_your_own_here_62dc3410aaf3
{

  background-image:url(http://static.squarespace.com/static/../background2.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call out the homepage specifically by using:

```
.homepage { }
```

or you can use a source code inspector and find the unique id as a class on the  element and call out any individual page like so:

```
.collection-51b4ef7de4b062dc3410aaf3 { }
```